# Perfect Squares Divisible by Repeating 1 Digits

Tags: divisibility, square-numbers

Are there any perfect squares with the form $$\frac{A(10)^n+B}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^k},$$ or, in other words, is $$\sqrt{\frac{A(10)^n+B}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^k}}$$ ever a natural number?

Comment: Since I think this is a spin-off from your previous question, you're also requiring that $A$ and $B$ are integers between $1$ and $9$, right?

Comment: That is precisely so